# ssh hostname.local on LAN? Why does it work?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have got a few ssh servers on my local network and noticed that instead of ssh-ing by IP address I can simply `ssh hostname.local`.

But not to all machines as some machines require that I ssh them by their IP address.

So my question is this, what protocol, feature is being use with the `name.local` pattern?
Why is it possible on some of my machine to use the hostname instead of IP address?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking

Comment: `Without zeroconf, a network administrator must set up network services, such as Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Domain Name System (DNS), or configure each computer's network settings manually.` I do have DHCP set up.

Comment: Irrelevant. The two can coexist; having DHCP doesn't rule out zeroconf.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ceejayoz, I needed to configure my zero configuration networking by installing avahi daemon

```
apt install avahi-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux server's DNS map's system name to it's IP as it work for internet/wan.

Look at file `/etc/hosts`. This file keeps mapping and routing.